# Make dnsmasq NOT server the local server?

Tags: dnsmasq

Is there a way to configure `dnsmasq` so that it **only** serves DNS requests from remote systems?  What I want is that ('internet' means outside my network):

1. Any DNS request from a program on the `dnsmasq` machine just uses the internet DNS servers and ignores `dnsmasq`
2. A DNS request from a remote system directed to the `dnsmasq` machine receives a response from `dnsmasq`, which could be a locally configured response or one that `dnsmasq` has relayed on to the internet DNS servers
3. Optionally restrict the IP addresses of remote servers permitted to query the `dnsmasq` system.

FYI my use case is needing to patch/respond locally to requests from an embedded system to add resilience with a remote server is down; I can't change the queried `hostname` so I want to be able to locally spoof the IP address, **but only affecting specific queries from this embedded system which I've manually directed to my local dnsmasq server**.

Answer (score 1):

After much digging, I stumbled across the answer.  The magic incantation required to achieve this is:

```
$ echo DNSMASQ_EXCEPT=lo | sudo tee --append /etc/default/dnsmasq
$ sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq
```

Look up DNSMASQ_EXCEPT for details but basically this stops `dnsmasq` providing DNS services to the `lo` interface.